# Запрос с таймаутом

Tags: android, kotlin

Осуществляется чтение содержимого по URL адресу примерно следующим компактным образом (используя Anko библиотеку):

```
doAsync {
    val text = URL("url").readText()
    uiThread {
        ...
    }
}
```

Можно ли (как можно) выполнить подобное чтение с учётом определённого таймаута?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить корутину с таймаутом:

```
suspend fun doSomeHardWork(): String {
    return URL("url").readText()
}

val result = withTimeoutOrNull(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) {
  async {
    doSomeHardWork()
   }.await()
}
```

Подсмотрел здесь: https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/coroutine-recipes

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться классом AsyncTask из библиотеки Android
У него есть три метода:

doInBackground – будет выполнен в новом потоке, здесь решаем все свои тяжелые задачи. Т.к. поток не основной - не имеет доступа к UI.

onPreExecute – выполняется перед doInBackground, имеет доступ к UI

onPostExecute – выполняется после doInBackground, имеет доступ к UI

Ниже представлен пример для начитки данных и последующего отображения их в приложении:

```
private class LoadDataAsyncTask constructor(private val onPreExec: () -> Unit, 
                                            private val onCancel: () -> Unit,
                                            private val onPostExec: (data: List<Task>?) -> Unit):
            AsyncTask<Unit, Unit, List<Task>>() {

        private var threadRepo: TaskRepository
        private val waitTymeout = 1000

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            onPreExec()
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Unit): List<Task>? {
            Thread.sleep(waitTymeout);
            return threadRepo.getTasks()
        }

        override fun onCancelled() {
            onCancel()
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(data: List<Task>?) {
            onPostExec(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Иcпользование будет таким:

```
        loadDataTask = LoadDataAsyncTask({
            /* Перед выполнением */
            setLoadingVisible(true)
        }, {
            /* Отмена выполнения */
            setLoadingVisible(false)
        }, {
            /* Успешное выполнение */
            tasks ->

            /* logic */

            setLoadingVisible(false)
        })
        loadDataTask?.execute(null)
```

При желании можно обернуть класс, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку UI нельзя было выполнять задачу, если она уже запущена, будет что-то вроде:

```
object LoadDataTask {

   // true - уже идёт загрузка данных
   val isLoadData = AtomicBoolean(false)

   private var loadDataTask: LoadDataAsyncTask? = null
   /* работа с LoadDataAsyncTask */
}

/* Использование */
if (!LoadDataTask.isLoadData.get()) {
    /* Можно выполнять задачу */
}
```